# Reading from a very large text file resource in C++

Tags: c++, windows, embedded-resource

We have some data in a text file which is built into our executable as a custom resource to be read at runtime. The size of this text file is over 7 million characters.

I can successfully search for and locate strings within the resource which appear near the top of the text file, but when attempting to search for terms a few million characters down, strstr returns NULL indicating that the string cannot be found. Is there a limit to the length of a string literal that can be stored in a char* or the amount of data that can be stored in an embedded resource? Code is shown below

```
char* data = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXT_FILE1), "TESTRESOURCE");
if(NULL != hRes)
{
    HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(hInst, hRes);
    if (hData)
    {
        DWORD dataSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hRes);
        data = (char*)LockResource(hData);
    }
    else
        break;

    char* pkcSearchResult = strstr(data, "NumListDetails");
    if ( pkcSearchResult != NULL )
    {
        // parse data
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in a loop, otherwise `break` won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the method you use for searching. `strstr` uses ANSI strings, and will terminate when it encounters a '\0' in the search domain.

You might use something like `memstr` (one of many implementations can be found [here](ftp://ftp.hq.eso.org/pub/linux/scisoft4/eclipse/eclipse/src/unix/memstr.c)).

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any output from GetLastError(), specifically after calling `SizeofResource`.

You can also check that `dataSize > 0` to ensure an error hasn't occurred.

```
DWORD dataSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hRes);
if(dataSize > 0)
{
    data = (char*)LockResource(hData);
}
else 
{
    //check error codes
}
```

[MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048.aspx)

Comment: dataSize is 7 million and something and 'data' contains a valid string that I can search through with strstr. I'll see what GetLastError returns and get back to you.

Comment: Aha. strlen(data) returns 3014. Well under the actual length returned by SizeOfResource.

Comment: Just reading up further on this, have you tried this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486.aspx -- using LoadString rather than casting as char* ? I'm not familiar with this process so ignore if this is way off the mark. Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible that you have NULL characters in your string?

Comment: It could be. The text file is an auto generated hash of various executable and configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was null characters in the data which prematurely ended the char* variable. To get around this I just had to read the data into a void pointer then copy it into a dynamically created array.

```
DWORD dataSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hRes);
void* pvData = LockResource(hData);
char* pcData = new char[dataSize];
memcpy_s(pcData,strlen(pcData),pvData,dataSize);
```